# Finding the next td element using j query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i find the next td element using jquery. 
I am trying to append a text or a div to the td element inside a particular tr. 
my tr is a server side control with tag runat=server
here is my query it is not working

```
   var cssdisable= function testcss(rowid) {
    if ($('#testcss').width() != 3) {
        var id = $(rowid).find('td');
        id.append('The following is not valid');
    }
}
```

this is how i am calling the function with in a click event

```
  cssdisable('<%=tr_myrow.ClientID %>');
```

It doesn't does anything, neither gives any error. i am trying to add a text after the td elemnent next to the row id passed.

Any ideas

here is the HTML 
        there is a row named tr_myrow

```
        <table id="tblstudysub_animal" class="bond_qbs_table" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <h3>
                            Select the study subject.<span class="red">*</span></h3>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="hide">Select the study subject.</legend>
                            <table id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_studysubj" value="Humans" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_0">Humans</label></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_studysubj" value="Non-Human primates" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_1">Non-Human primates</label></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_studysubj" value="Rodents" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_2">Rodents</label></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_studysubj" value="Others" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_studysubj_3">Others</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_tr_myrow">
                        <td valign="top">

                        <div id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_studysub_popul">
                            <h3>
                                Select your study subject.<span class="red">*</span></h3>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="hide">Select your study subject.</legend>
                                <table id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_study_popul" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_study_popul_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_study_popul" value="Individuals" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_study_popul_0">Individuals</label></td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_study_popul_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_study_popul" value="Population" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_study_popul_1">Population</label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>


       <div id="testcss">
    </div>
```

I ma trying to add that text to the td in that row...

i hope this makes more clear...

Comment: Can we see the rendered cssdisable function call?

Comment: How should we know without seeing the HTML, we'll just be guessing something like `$(rowid).next('td');` ?

Comment: @adeneo im guessing `$('#' + rowid).find('td')`

Comment: may be jquery next() function can be useful to you

Comment: You've been a user here for 7 months and have asked dozens of questions. Surely you know by now that you need to post all relevant information needed to represent the problem.

Comment: hit F12 and inspect the gridview to see how it renders the row id tags. most likely though you'll need the td id tags.

Comment: Is this asp.net? Please add the server-side tag to the question.

Comment: wow... 38 questions and not a single accepted answer.. you should probably [read the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: so.. you have created functions `append` and `testcss` but you are calling one named `cssdisable`. where is that one ? and where is the `#test` in your html ?

Comment: that was a typo. i have a test div at the HTML at the end of the page

Comment: @user2664298 although it has an id of `testcss` and not `test` as your javascript..

Comment: u know i am using that to check whether the css is disabled or not. if the css is disabled then i add a text to the td of the tr whose id i am passing in the function. that was the idea

Comment: i am just saying that you check the `#test` element but the real id is `testcss`. Anyway the major issue is that id's need to be queried with `#` so try `cssdisable('#<%=tr_myrow.ClientID %>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are trying to query for the `td` by its id but are not using the `#` at the start of the selector..

try `cssdisable('#<%=tr_myrow.ClientID %>');`

Also in order to stick to just the `td` child of the `tr` use `.children()` instead of `.find('td')` (*which will find all descendant `td` elements*)

so

```
var cssdisable = function testcss(rowid) {
    if ($('#testcss').width() != 3) {
        var id = $(rowid).children().first();
        id.append('The following is not valid');
    }
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/D4z9b/ (*using your example HTML*)

Answer (score -1):

Give your `<td>..</td>` elements meaningful ids during the table build phase (if you don't build it, just assign them before starting any processing using a separate call) and then generate the id. Something like `tableName + '_' + row + '_'` will probably should do you fine.